# Cant seem to startup my .net Maui program after some changes

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

For the last few days, if been struggling to create a .net Maui application. If worked with xamarin before, but I'm now creating my first maui application.

Currenty Im getting the following errors:

`error NETSDK1136: The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property) when using Windows Forms or WPF, or referencing projects or packages that do so.`

```
XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Application".
XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "Shell".
XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ResourceDictionary".
XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ResourceDictionary".
XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage".
XamlC error XFC0000 : Cannot resolve type "ContentPage".
```

I also don't want this application to run on windows. Only on android and ios.
i tried removing this code:

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
...
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
```

but it still doesn't work.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction so that I can solve these issues?

Comment: Per [the solution](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12308#issuecomment-1366172357) suggested by greg, you can try to add this line  the TargetFramework tag in the iOS and Android project files:`<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>` to fix it.